# Ruby on rails: Update multiple records in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose that I have a hash of hashes as following. One can use "**update**" to update all the records as follows.

```
 people = { 1 => { "first_name" => "David", "last_name" => "Freeman" }, 2 => { "first_name" => "Jeremy", "last_name" => "Stone" } .....}

 Person.update(people.keys, people.values)
```

This will run an UPDATE query for each record. How can I use "**update_all**" to achieve this which runs a single query for all the records?

Referred to ([this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all)) but couldn't find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SRack I couldn't figure out what should be the parameters if I need to update a few and with different values for each record.

Comment: How would a plain SQL query look like that does what you try to build with ActiveRecord?

Comment: @spickermann insert into persons(id,first_name,last_name) values (1,"David","Freeman"), (2,"Jeremy","Stone") on duplicate key update first_name=values(first_name), last_name=values(last_name);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. This is not the nature of "update_all". Imagine writing a SQL query for your required result, it will involve matching each id and then doing the required update for each id, hence contrasting it from what "update_all" does.

You should use "update_all" when performing same update over a set of tuples, but obviously in your case first_name and last_name are different for each tuple.

I think using just "update" will not affect performance much, considering the id's are indexed. However, you always have the option of writing native SQL statements.